# Virtual function mechanism with reference to virtual constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, runtime-error, vtable

This was the question asked to me in one of the interviews.

If Vtable is created in compile time, and `vptr` is assigned to object in runtime, then why compiler gives compile time error if we have virtual constructor in our class?

I explained whole mechanism. But he was more interested in '**Why compile time error not runtime error**'

I told him the that the C++ guidelines are chalked such that so compiler sends error at compile time.

Can you please provide me the reason for the same

Comment: there are no such thing as virtual contructor in c++

Comment: And it's essentially correct *answer* @up.

Comment: You might want to explain what *virtual constructor* means to you or the interviewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Why compile time error not run time error?**

A runtime error occurs when an exception scenario occurs at runtime. While a compile time error occurs when the compiler detects that particular construct is not allowed by the C++ standard as valid C++ construct.
The C++ Standard does not allow constructor to be marked as `virtual`. Hence the compiler detects it as violation of language grammer rules and flags an error.

As to answer why virtual constructor is not allowed in C++.
Bjarne answers the Q on his faq page as:

> A virtual call is a mechanism to get work done given partial information. In particular, "virtual" allows us to call a function knowing only any interfaces and not the exact type of the object. To create an object you need complete information. In particular, you need to know the exact type of what you want to create. Consequently, a "call to a constructor" cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 9):

Tricky question with simple answer - because there are *no* virtual constructors in `C++`.

---

In the ISO standards, ISO/IEC 14882:2003 and ISO/IEC 14882:2011, 12.1 Constructors, point 4:

> A constructor shall not be virtual (10.3) or static (9.4). A constructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. A constructor shall not be declared const, volatile, or const volatile (9.3.2). const and volatile semantics (7.1.5.1) are not applied on an object under construction. Such semantics only come into effect once the constructor for the most derived object (1.8) ends.

And this can be caught compile-time.

Comment: Of course this is right... I was trying to read between the lines what he might mean with *virtual constructor* and the whole thing, but keeping things simple... +1

Comment: I guess it's just a pitfall, which is pretty good for interview question, by the way.

Comment: But the question is *why* is it like this?

Comment: @juanchopanza - I'm not sure you have seen my last edit, I just did :? I added, that this could be caught compile-time, that's why it's not run-time error.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No. The question is "Why is it diagnosed at compile time?"

Answer (score 3):

The rules of the language do not allow it, because it doesn't make sense to have a virtual constructor. How would this constructor be invoked? A common approach in C++ to construct different derived instances of a certain base class is a factory method:

```
#include <memory>

// the parameters determine the derived type to be instantiated.
std::unique_ptr<IFoo> fooFactory(some parameters);
```

**Note** The choice of [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) should be dictated by the ownership policy. This example uses unique ownership.

Comment: Eeew (returning) owning raw pointers. Return an `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @daknøk I can, and I would do that in my code, but returning the pointer is the classic pattern seen in most of the literature.

Comment: @daknøk most of the literature if old, and pre-dates move semantics, which are a reasonably recent addition to the language.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Smart pointers, however, have been part of the C++ std lib since 2003 — almost a decade.

Comment: @juanchopanza and that makes it still OK because? About any decent and recent C++ compiler can do move semantics by now.

Comment: @daknøk unfortunately not everyone is allowed to use that. You must agree that this kind of thing has been a big problem in the language for a very long time (witness ``auto_ptr``). And unfortunately, it will take a while until everyone has access to a C++11 compiler and is allowed to use it.

Comment: If you're *not allowed to use that*, you should change your workplace.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz An interesting idea, however I have not come accross a single place that uses C++11. My approach is to try to change that, but fully compliant compilers would help.

Comment: The current version of C++ is C++11 and as such, unless the OP specifically states otherwise, a question should be answered with C++11 in mind. This means this answer is currently teaching bad practice which must be corrected.

Comment: To clarify, I think this answer should just use smart pointers, rather then slip them in as some sort of sly comment

Comment: @juanchopanza yay! much better

Answer (score -1):

In C++ "virtual" means that what is done will depend at runtime on the effective class of an object and will not depend only on the type of the variable.

A "virtual" constructor is something that doesn't really make sense because you don't have an object yet (you want to build one) so you have no class to depend on for the decision.

Sometimes with "virtual constructor" what is intended in C++ is a pattern in which you are able to build an object without knowing the exact class... for example:

```
class Document {
    public:
        static Document *create(...);
    private:
        Document(...);
};

...

// Just use Document::create instead of new Document
std::unique_ptr<Document> p = Document::create(...);
```

In this case the users of the class are not able to call the constructor (it's private), but they can only call a **static method** that is public and that will return a pointer to an instance. The construction itself will be handled by this function and the returned object will not be a necessarily a `Document` instance, but an instance of some class **derived** from `Document` that you don't know and that is not publicly exposed.
This allows for example to decide at runtime the exact class depending on the environment or on the parameters specified in the call to `create`.

This is called "virtual constructor" because the constructor being called will be decided at runtime. It's not however the same thing as a virtual method call in C++ because virtual dispatching in C++ depends only on the class of the instance (but as said before this makes no sense for a constructor because the object doesn't exist yet, so you cannot decide depending on its real class).

Comment: Eeew (returning) owning raw pointers. Return an `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza then you are not using C++

Comment: I don't think this deserves down-vote. Nobody says, that using `C++03` is (already) _bad practice_. And raw pointers are not "forbidden".

Comment: @KirilKirov Nobody said that it was downvoted because of the pointer, either.

Comment: The current version of C++ is C++11 and as such, unless the OP specifically states otherwise, a question should be answered with C++11 in mind. This means this answer is currently teaching bad practice which must be corrected.

Comment: @Kiril: What argument is _that?_ There's a lot that isn't forbidden in C++, yet is clearly seen as "bad and shouldn't be used." It's one of C++' strengths that it forbids little, and does little to push you to certain programming styles. Instead you should use your own judgment. Well, mine is to not to use raw pointers unless you know exactly what you're doing. And certainly don't teach using them.

Comment: FWIW, the first downvote was mine, and precisely for the reason given in the first comment, which I upvoted to indicate approval, rather than duplicating it. (I had also downvoted the other answer suggesting raw pointers, but removed my downvote when it was amended to include a strong hint towards smart pointer usage.)

Comment: @sbi - ok, I don't want to argue, because it's going to become a really long discussion, where everybody's right and wrong in the same time, because there's no _universal_ answer for this.

Comment: @sbi I use almost only smart pointers. I know, they should be preferred for a thousand reasons, but I still think, that using raw pointers is not really _bad practice_. Just wanted to mention that, not to sound like - "ah, I don't use smart pointers, they su*k" :)

Comment: @sbi A, now I see the edit of your comment and what I completely agree is "not to use raw pointers unless you know exactly what you're doing" - 100% agree with this one. This is something else, now.

Comment: Doesn't `new` return an owning naked pointer? That `create` method is just playing the role of `new`, but allows your code to ignore the exact class. If you want to wrap it in a smart pointer then do it.